# How do I install markupsafe into my Flask virtualenv?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, virtualenv, osx-snow-leopard

I've been doing the following tutorial and looking it over may help you figure out what I haven't been able to:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world/

I'm working on a OS X (10.6.8) with Python 2.7.6. I'm pretty sure that I followed all the instructions (on page 1) to a T and have checked that the required libraries are indeed in the modules list in the python virtualenv however, I get this error message when I try to run 'run.py':

```
    File "/Users/user1/Desktop/flasktut/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 520, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
    ImportError: No module named markupsafe
```

I need markupsafe in my virtualenv - how do I get it in there?

Answer (score 4):

The command to check what packages you have installed is:

```
$ pip freeze
```

If you don't see an entry for `MarkupSafe` there then you can install it with:

```
$ pip install markupsafe
```

Comment: hi Miguel thanks. For some reason whenever I try to download markupsafe I get the following error: 'SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler'. As far as I can tell this problem occurs when you haven't downloaded Xcode. From what I've seen I'm supposed to download Xcode 4 (because I am using OS 10.6.8) which will allow me to DL markupsafe (and others where this problem occurs). Should I update to Mavericks and then DL Xcode5 (being that it is free?)

Comment: There must be a bug in the installer for MarkupSafe, because the extension offers a C optimized version for when you have a compiler installed and a Python version for when you don't. The compiler detection must not be working well for OSX. I think you'll be fine with XCode4 or 5, if you don't want to upgrade to Mavericks right away just install Xcode 4 and leave the bigger upgrade for later.

Comment: Just wanted to update. I wiped laptop and installed Mavericks, then XCode5. Everything working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not work. it(markupsafe) exist with freeze output version (0.0.0)